# Javascript function variable going null outside loop

Tags: javascript

Below is the code I want to be checked, not sure what i am doing wrong here, but the value of variable checkedValue is not working outside the for loop.

If I test from the part i've commented [i.e. inside for loop], its working.

I've tested with declaring the array variable as [0] as well to check if its having at least the initial value 0, but is not displaying anything, as if the variable is null.

```
<script>
                    var checkedValue = [];
                    function getItemId() 
                    {
                        //var checkedValue = [];
                        var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('pick');
                    for(var i=0; i<=inputElements.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(inputElements[i].checked)
                        {
                            checkedValue.push(inputElements[i].value);   
                        }
                    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedValue;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedValue;
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: If you want to use it outside of the function you need to declare it outside of the function.

Comment: var checkedValue; needs to be outside the function as jason stated

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) to learn more about the scope in javascript.

Comment: @Burki https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRZNb4GDOPI - I think it's the best explanation. :)

Comment: Interesting that `checkedValue` used in same scope where it was defined but because of formatting it is difficult to see :)

Comment: yes its used in the same scope,  @Jason/Eitan -- I am not using this variable outside the function, have declared it inside and i am trying to print onto screen from inside as well.

Comment: now as per posts below i've tried declaring variable outside function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make few changes in your code:
`for(var i=0; i<=inputElements.length; ++i){` change to
`for(var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++){`

And `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedValue` to `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedValue.join(',')`.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, but it's not making any difference, also document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = checkedValue is working fine inside loop

Comment: Fix condition i<=inputElements.length, remove '='. It should be less not less or equal, i<=inputElements.length.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, that indeed was the issue, but can you help me explain how = was making the value in variable checkedValue null.

Comment: If you have 3 input items, the length of inputElements is 3, but indexing of array start from 0. So you have inputElements[0], inputElements[1], inputElements[2].
If you have for(var i=0; i<=inputElements.length; i++) this code will try to retrieve inputElements[3] and this will fire error.
But for(var i=0; i<inputElements.length; i++) will retrieve just  inputElements[2]. 
Cause in condition you have less than 3 (<), instead of less or equal 3 (<=)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `checkedValue` is declared inside of the function `getItemId` yet you are trying to access it outside the function. Change the scope of your variable and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Mr. White -- Variable checkedValue has now been tested from outside function as well, but still its not working..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies with the [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) of variables in javaScript.

You can either declare `var checkedValue = [];` outside your function, or you can ommit `var`in the declaration, to make it global.

You should use the first variant though, which is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Strict mode disallows leaving out the `var`, so I'd never even recommend that at this point.

Comment: @Burki -- I have updated my question to correct formatting of the script so  that it becomes more clear, variable was defined and used inside function, Also as i mentioned if used it from inside the loop its working fine. I have also tried declaring variable outside the function..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it doesn't work but have you tried the scenario when returning checkedValue?

```
<script>
                    function getItemId() 
                    {
                        var checkedValue = [];
                        var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('pick');
                        for(var i=0; i<=inputElements.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(inputElements[i].checked)
                            {
                                checkedValue.push(inputElements[i].value);   
                            }
                        }
                        return checkedValue;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getItemId();
</script>
```

Comment: well that basically was the requirement [to return checkedValue], but since it was not returning any value, I have tried printing value of checkedValue

Comment: i've tried this the script you shared as well, but still its not printing any value, whereas if I put this return statement in the for loop it prints value from the first iteration and then exits